# Hidding top border in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to build simple pricing table using bootstrap 4 card element, but i can't find solution to one problem.

[image: Screenshot]

```
  .card {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    padding: 2.25rem 0;
    position: relative;

    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 0%;
      border: 3px solid $primary-color;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    &:hover {
      transform: scale(1.05);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
      box-shadow: 0 20px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);

      &:after {
        border: 3px solid $primary-color;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

[Live Codepen](https://codepen.io/danzawadzki/pen/mOoeNM)

This is code responsible for drawing line in top part of the tables on the hover. The problem is i have no idea how to hide this small green rectangle in the left top corner of each table. I was trying to make border white and change to green once customer hover table. It works, but then fade effect is visible. I would prefer to keep it as it's now, just somehow get rid of this rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove border from `:after` and add `height: 3px` instead, also remove border from `:after` on `:hover`

```
   .card {
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
        box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        padding: 2.25rem 0;
        position: relative;

        &:after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 0%;
          height: 3px;
          background: $primary-color;
          transition: 0.5s;
        }

        &:hover {
          transform: scale(1.05);
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
          box-shadow: 0 20px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);

          &:after {
            width: 100%;
          }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly! Will keep in mind, that i can use height in :after selector! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)